# Simple Recursion output calling recursion twice

Tags: c

This is how I tried it. The main part uses `fun(9)`. So 9 does not equal or less than one. And it calls `fun(9/3)` two times and prints `n` which is 9. Where am I wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(int n){
  if(n<=1) printf("*");
  else{
    fun(n/3);
    fun(n/3);
    printf("%d",n);
  }
}

int main(void){
    fun(9);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: I see two calls to `fun(n/3);` is that not what you expect?

Comment: In what way do you consider you're wrong? What are you expecting as output?

Comment: the answer says it outputs, **3**39 i really dont know how they got that

Comment: When formatting code, lay it out in the edit box as you want it to appear, then select it all and use the **`{}`** button above the edit box to indent it all.  Avoid tabs; usually, use 4 spaces per indentation level.

Comment: Such questions expect only one answer: user debugger.

Answer (score 3):

When called as `fun(9)`, the code shown does print `**3**39`.

- The first call has `n == 9`.
- Consequently, if calls `fun(3)`, then `fun(3)` again, and then prints `9`.
- The first of the two calls `fun(3)` calls `fun(1)`, which prints a `*`, then calls `fun(1)` again and prints another `*`, and then prints `3`.
- The second of the two calls does the same.

Answer (score 2):

Your output should be 
* * 3 * * 3 9

[image: recursion]

Answer (score 1):

If you can't see how it works, then do it by hand and fill in the values instead of the variable name:

Pass 1:

```
void fun(9){             // first pass n=9
  if(9<=1) printf("*");  // nope, that's not true
  else{
    fun(9/3);            // call the function again with n = 9/3 = 3
```

Pass 2:

```
void fun(3){             // second pass n=3
  if(3<=1) printf("*");  // nope, that's not true
  else{
    fun(3/3);            // call the function again with n = 3/3 = 1
```

Pass 3:

```
void fun(1){             // third pass n=1
  if(1<=1) printf("*");  // yes! so print first *
  else{                  // this function is only an if and an else, we hit the if
                         // so it just drops out now
```

So pass #3 and we hit the lowest level of the recursive call, now Pass 2 will continue execution where it left off:

Pass 2b:

```
void fun(3){             // second pass n=3       (did this already)
  if(3<=1) printf("*");  // nope, that's not true (did this already)
  else{
    fun(3/3);            // call the function with n = 1 (did this already)
    fun(3/3);            // next recursive call, again with n = 1
```

Now this will repeat the "pass #3" code, again printing a second *, then it will return and continue execution where it left off:

Pass 2c:

```
void fun(3){             // second pass n=3       (did this already)
  if(3<=1) printf("*");  // nope, that's not true (did this already)
  else{
    fun(3/3);            // call the function with n = 1 (did this already)
    fun(3/3);            // call again with n = 1 (did this already)
    printf("%d", 3);     // print 3
```

At this point the output is: `**3` Pass #2 is now complete so we go all the way back up and resume Pass #1 where it left off:

Pass 1b:

```
void fun(9){             // first pass n=9        (did this already)
  if(9<=1) printf("*");  // nope, that's not true (did this already)
  else{
    fun(9/3);            // call the function again with n = 3 (did this already)
    fun(9/3);            // now call the function again with n = 9/3 = 3
```

From here you can see that we're going to repeat the Pass 2 logic producing another `**3` then we'll return to Pass1 a final time to print the `9`

A final output of: `**3**39`